# Add class to a submenu container in Yii2 Bootstrap4 Nav widget

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

I'm using the Nav widget in Yii2. I have a dropdown menu as part of the nav menu but the dropdown is very long and extends beyond the bottom of the page and doesn't scroll. To solve this I am trying to add the `pre-scrollable` class to the submenu container. Try as I might I can't seem to make it work.

In the Yii manual for the Nav widget (https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap/doc/api/2.0/yii-bootstrap-nav) under the `$Items` public property it says:

> dropDownOptions: array, optional, the HTML options that will passed to
> the yii\bootstrap\Dropdown widget.

I've also looked at the man page for the Dropdown widget (https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap/doc/api/2.0/yii-bootstrap-dropdown).

The code I have for my Nav widget is like:

```
echo Nav::widget([
    'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav ml-auto'],
    'items' => [
        ['label' => 'Home', 'url' => ['/site/index']],
        ['label' => 'About', 'url' => ['/site/about']],
        [
            'label' => 'Dropdown menu',

            //'dropDownOptions' => ['options' => ['class' => 'pre-scrollable']],
            //'dropDownOptions' => ['class' => 'pre-scrollable'],
            //'dropDownOptions' => ['submenuOptions' => ['class' => 'pre-scrollable']],
            //'submenuOptions' => ['class' => 'pre-scrollable'],
            //'submenuOptions' => ['options' => ['class' => 'pre-scrollable']],
            //'submenuOptions' => ['dropDownOptions' => ['class' => 'pre-scrollable']],
            //'dropDownOptions' => ['dropDownOptions' => ['class' => 'pre-scrollable']],
            //'submenuOptions' => ['submenuOptions' => ['class' => 'pre-scrollable']],
            //'options' => ['submenuOptions' => ['class' => 'pre-scrollable']],
            //'options' => ['class' => 'pre-scrollable'],
            //'options' => ['dropDownOptions' => ['class' => 'pre-scrollable']],

            'items' => [
                ['label' => 'Dropdown menu item 1', 'url' => '#'],
                ['label' => 'Dropdown menu item 2', 'url' => '#'],
                ...
            ],
        ],
        ['label' => 'Contact', 'url' => ['/site/contact']],
    ],
]);
```

The commented out lines are some of the different ways I've tried to 'pass the HTML options to the yii\bootstrap\Dropdown widget' (in order of increasing desperation).

Please can someone put me right?

Thanks in anticipation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option `dropDownOptions` is tested successfully on Yii version 2.0.11.2 and Bootstrap v3.3.7:

```
'dropDownOptions' => ['class' => 'pre-scrollable'],
```

The result is additional class of  tag contained submenu items

```
<ul id="w4" class="pre-scrollable dropdown-menu">
```

If you are using `yii2-bootstrap4` - that options apparently renamed to `dropdownOptions`.

See `Nav::renderDropdown()` in the sources:

```
/**
 * Renders the given items as a dropdown.
 * This method is called to create sub-menus.
 * @param array $items the given items. Please refer to [[Dropdown::items]] for the array structure.
 * @param array $parentItem the parent item information. Please refer to [[items]] for the structure of this array.
 * @return string the rendering result.
 * @throws \Exception
 */
protected function renderDropdown($items, $parentItem)
{
    /** @var Widget $dropdownClass */
    $dropdownClass = $this->dropdownClass;
    return $dropdownClass::widget([
        'options' => ArrayHelper::getValue($parentItem, 'dropdownOptions', []),
        'items' => $items,
        'encodeLabels' => $this->encodeLabels,
        'clientOptions' => false,
        'view' => $this->getView(),
    ]);
}
```

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap4/blob/219d19fba47b5499f01764789c3cd3ce7306e0f9/src/Nav.php#L207